# Reading App.conf and Log4j.properties from Spark submit command

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, log4j, spark-submit

I am trying to pass application.conf and Log4j.properties which are in my jar but I want to pass them externally. I tried it through spark submit command which is as below:

```
/opt/apps/spark/bin/spark-submit 
    --files /opt/apps/spark/code/src/main/resources/application.conf 
    --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=/opt/apps/spark/code/src/main/resources/application.conf 
    --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=/opt/apps/spark/code/src/main/resources/application.conf 
    --driver-java-options Dlog4j.configuration=File:///opt/apps/spark/code/src/main/resources/Log4j.properties 
    --class com.ericsson.dnb.main.staging.SnifferReportStatus /opt/apps/spark/code/target/scala-2.12/dnb-reporting-1A-4.0.0.ft.jar
```

It does not throw any error but it's only reading log4j.properties from the path specified and taking application.conf from the JAR itself. Is there any way where we can supply both these configuration outside the JAR via Spark submit command ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you forgot to append `file://` to your application  conf file while you did the same for log4j.properties file.

Below piece of code should work

```
/opt/apps/spark/bin/spark-submit --files File:///opt/apps/spark/code/src/main/resources/application.conf --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=File:///opt/apps/spark/code/src/main/resources/application.conf --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=File:///opt/apps/spark/code/src/main/resources/application.conf --driver-java-options -Dlog4j.configuration=File:///opt/apps/spark/code/src/main/resources/Log4j.properties --class com.ericsson.dnb.main.staging.SnifferReportStatus /opt/apps/spark/code/target/scala-2.12/dnb-reporting-1A-4.0.0.ft.jar
```

Comment: Hi Vikas, I got the following error
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: File
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)

I don't think so it's because of not adding File:// because in the logs i can see that application.conf is getting stored in spark's local HDFS. What I think the issue is, by adding --driver-java-options , it's overriding the previously loaded applicationg.conf and ignoring it and fetching it from the JAR.

Comment: Needed a way around for this. So that both the configurations are loaded from submit command itself and not from the JAR. Any help will be appreciated.